# Rscript Subprocess Python

Tags: python, r

By google I have found that the way to call R code is to use the following:

```
subprocess.call("Rscript" + " /path/Rscript.R")

# The reason there is an add statment is because in actual code I have a 
variable of where the script is.
```

On my home computer such code works. I am now working on a Server machine. If while in the the direcotry of my code I run

```
Rscript /path/Rscript.R
```

it works.
However when I try to run it from the python code I get No such file or Directory. I have made sure Rscript was in my path (because I could Run it from command line).

Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried running from ~/path to it, ./path to it, /absolutepathtoit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a needless parenthesis at the end of the line:

```
subprocess.call("Rscript" + "/path/Rscript.R"))
                                              )
```

---

And, you need to insert a space between a command and arguments. Otherwise `Rscript/path/Rscript.R` is recognized as a command.

```
subprocess.call("Rscript" + " " + "/path/Rscript.R")
                            ^^^
```

Or pass a list:

```
subprocess.call(["Rscript", "/path/Rscript.R"])
```

Comment: The parenthesis and lack of space comes from my sloppy editing to make the path smaller. It is there in the acutal code. I am going to try to use the list method.

Comment: @user2100799, If passing a list also does not work, try it with `shell=True` argument.

Comment: The list worked! Although I read on this site that using shell=True was advised against. I can only accept after waiting for 5 mins.

Comment: Glad you got the problem solved. Depending on exactly how the Python+R is getting executed, you should give [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2.html) a go since--in certain circumstances--it could be much more efficient to use R code that way.